# Can I download Vagrant for Debian on an Ubuntu computer?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, virtualization, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Desktop).

I need to download and install Vagrant on it. However, there isn't a specific release for Ubuntu; only Debian and CentOS are available.

So, since Ubuntu is Debian-based, should I download the one for Debian?

Comment: vagrant should be available in apt repos, `sudo apt install vagrant` should do

Answer (score 1):

You can install vagrant through `apt` or `dpkg` :

```
sudo apt-get install vagrant
```

Or download the `.deb` file from [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) or you can choose a specific version from [here](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/) , there is an example:

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.9.2/vagrant_1.9.2_x86_64.deb
sudo dpkg -i vagrant_1.9.2_x86_64.deb
```

Comment: The vagrant deb in apt repository is outdated and has problems like this one: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9788